# Why is suddenly this java security warning shown on our applet

Tags: java, security, applet, mixed-code

A customer got this Java security warning on one of our ancient java components on a web site we develop:

[image: Java has discovered application components that could indicate a security concerns.]

The java applet is a tiny applet that does very little (it is simply a dropdown with the ability to write freetext). Is it a simple way to avoid this security warning?

The applet is something we have developed a long time ago, which has been running in our web solutions for years.

Comment: Have you seen the jQuery UI combobox?  It may achieve your intent without Java.  http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sun/Oracle changed something in Java SE 6 Update 19 and up in relation to [mixing signed and unsigned code](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/mixed_code.html). The linked article has tips on solving this.

Comment: It is our experience that the "change setting in Control Panel" does not work 100%.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen - Not that it is an approach I would try(1), but have you reported the failure of the Control Panel based solution to Oracle?  1) Only for the fact that changing the CP seems a solution targeted at large companies where the Sys Admin can change the installation/options of every Java set-up in the shop.

Comment: @Andrew, we didn't have time to make a thorough investigation when this happened, and hence could not do a proper bug report.  We just found that this happened again (for a Java WebStart application) even with all switches set properly.  A proper fix is scheduled for our next release.